# Are there linguistic reasons for the Dormouse to be treated like a piece of furniture in ‘Wonderland?’

Tags: alice-in-wonderland, lewis-carroll

In *A Mad Tea-Party* the Hatter and March Hare mistreat the Dormouse, as they

> ...were using it as a cushion, resting their elbows on it, and talking over its head.
> <sub>(p. 95, original pagination for this and all subsequent quotations)</sub>

During the Trial, near the end of the book, Alice begins to grow in size, and thus to squish the Dormouse, who tells her:

> I wish you wouldn’t squeeze so, said the Dormouse, who was sitting next to her. “I can hardly breathe.”
> <sub>(p. 105)</sub>

Whence the using of the Dormouse as a cushion, the resting of elbows on him, and the squeezing of this character?

Answer (score 69):

The wordsmith Lewis Carroll loved to use puns and other types of plays on words in his “Nonsense” writings.  The word “Dormouse” provided him with such a clever play on words, because this word was sometimes confused with the word *dormeuse*. Here is how the OED describes this confusion

Dormeuse, n.
...
Forms:  Also 1700s -ouse.
...
Etymology: French; feminine of dormeur sleeper, applied to articles convenient for sleeping, < dormir to sleep.

It just so happen that during the Victorian Era, one of these articles convenient for sleeping was a Dormeuse Cushion (for a write up and picture of this object, see Paterson,s Magazine, Vol. 40, 1861, p. 475, available at
https://books.google.ca/books?id=HIzNAAAAMAAJ&pg=RA1-PA475&dq=dormeuse+cushion&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi2y_7p5J_vAhUTvJ4KHfA3DvwQ6AEwAHoECAMQAg#v=onepage&q=dormeuse%20cushion&f=false )

Comment: You should link the image here along with any relevant quotes, in case the link dies off

Comment: So, a dormeuse was something you could sit or lay on, and a dormouse is a type of rodent, so the Dormouse is both?

Comment: Yes. Like a mouse can have both a tail and a tale, the Dormouse can be both a rodent and a pillow in Carroll’s dream-like world of Wonderland.

Comment: the same french root as in dormitory.

Comment: Yes, exactly so.

Comment: Also the same root as "dormant."

Comment: Huh. I had assumed it was a play on the similarity between _dormouse_ and _doormat_ (in [the idiomatic sense](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/doormat) of someone who is a pushover), but I think your answer makes more sense.

Comment: It might also be worth mentioning that dormice are especially known for their [unusually long hibernation period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dormouse#Hibernation), and were thought of (by Victorians especially) as always being sleepy. This makes the pun associating them with a type of pillow especially fitting.